# Template literals in R

Tags: r

In JavaScript, template literals may be used to insert a dynamic value into text.
Here is an example:

```js
const name = "John";
console.log(`Hello ${name}, how are you?`;)
```

This would print `Hello John, how are you?` to the console.

An approach to this in R would be to use `paste0`

```
name = "John"
print(paste0("Hello ", name, ", how are you?"))
```

This becomes quite a hassle if you are dealing with long texts that require multiple dynamic variables.

What are some alternatives to template literals in R?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_glue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`str_glue`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_glue.html) from the [`stringr`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html) package to directly refer to an R object:

```
library(stringr)
name = "John"
str_glue("Hello {name}, how are you?")

# Hello John, how are you?
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the versatile `sprintf()`-function

```
name = "John"
sprintf( "Hello %s, how are you", name )
#[1] "Hello John, how are you"
```

Comment: How does this work for strings where you need to insert multiple dynamic inputs?